# What do I need for doing this regex or split?

Tags: php, regex, split

I have strings like the following that I have to split:

```
Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress
Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli
Items::getCode+Address::getName,CODSITE+Items::getSample,Items::getItemID
Other, CODSITE, CODSITE2
```

Into:

```
array(
    array(
    0 => 'Other',
    1 => 'CODSITE',
    2 => array(
        'Items' => 'getCodCdeCli',
        'Address' => 'getNameAddress'
       )
    ),
//...
)
```

Each comma involve new information, if we have a '+' we need to append both data. If we have '::' we need to get first part as key of the result information.

For beginning this solution I have tried to split this on comma:

```
$re = "/([^,]+)/"; 
$str = "Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress"; 
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

for now with this regex I have this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Other' (length=5)
      1 => string 'CODSITE' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress' (length=43)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Other' (length=5)
      1 => string 'CODSITE' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress' (length=43)
```

Which is wrong. I have same result twice.. and line 2 => [...] is not split (which is normal with my regex)

Comment: Do it in 2 pass. First split by comma and then match in the 3rd element of the array.

Comment: This seems like it can be achieved without using a regex. Have you tried solving this problem using `split` function on the particular characters you are interested in?

Comment: This string i get, come from a PHP form, and can be completely different with more than 3 parts, and can repeat this example as many time as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Richard Parnaby-King answer. This is the solution, in fact no regex is needed even if i'm sure we can use it for the same result.

```
$lines = array(
    0 => 'Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress',
    2 => 'Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli',
    3 => 'Items::getCode+Address::getName,CODSITE+Items::getSample,Items::getItemID',
    4 => 'Other, CODSITE, CODSITE2',
);

foreach ($lines as $input) {
    $informations = explode(',', $input);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($informations as $information) {
        if(strpos($information, '+') !== FALSE) {
            $classes = explode('+',$information);
            $temp = array();
            foreach($classes as $subresult) {
                if(strpos($subresult,'::') !== FALSE) {
                    $classAndMethod = explode('::',$subresult);
                    $temp[$classAndMethod[0]] = $classAndMethod[1];
                } else {
                    $temp[] = trim($subresult);
                }
            }
            $result[] = $temp;
        } elseif (strpos($information, '::') !== FALSE) {
            $classAndMethod = explode('::',$information);
            $result[][$classAndMethod[0]] = $classAndMethod[1];
        } else {
            $result[] = trim($information);
        }
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

It works !

Comment: 1+ Glad you got a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it in single pass is by using [`array_combine` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) like this:

```
$str = 'Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress';
if ( preg_match_all('~(?|[,+]([^,+]+)::([^,+]+)|([^,]+))~', $str, $m) )
   print_r( array_combine ( $m[1], $m[2] ) );
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [Other] =>
    [CODSITE] =>
    [Items] => getCodCdeCli
    [Address] => getNameAddress
)
```

Comment: It's cool, but too strict. My data varies depending on the input data (see Edit). The solution must be global.

Comment: I think you need to show expected matches for each line if sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be regex? It might be possible to achieve this with a couple of `explode`s and `foreach` loops:

```
$str = 'Other,CODSITE,Items::getCodCdeCli+Address::getNameAddress';

//new entry per comma (,)
$results = explode(',',$str);

//check each entry for array information
foreach($results as &$result) {
    if(strpos($result,'+') !== FALSE) {

        //explode array information
        $bits1 = explode('+',$result);
        $result = array();
        foreach($bits1 as &$subresult) {

            //format array information into key => value pairs
            if(strpos($subresult,'::') !== FALSE) {
                $bits = explode('::',$subresult);
                $result[$bits[0]] = $bits[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($results);

/**
 * array (size=3)
 *   0 => string 'Other' (length=5)
 *   1 => string 'CODSITE' (length=7)
 *   2 => array (size=2)
 *       'Items' => string 'getCodCdeCli' (length=12)
 *       'Address' => string 'getNameAddress' (length=14)
 */
```

Comment: This solution only works for the 1st and 3rd strings supplied

Comment: This is a beginning of what I want, thank you. But it does not work for my other sample data, must be something more global.